# Where are Windows 10 desktop wallpapers stored?

Tags: windows-10, path, desktop-customization

I plugged in a thumb drive to my pc, right-clicked on an image, and chose 'Set as desktop background'. The thumb drive was subsequently stolen. Windows obviously creates a copy on the image since it remains as the desktop background even after the thumb drive is removed. My question is, where exactly is this file stored?

Answer (score 15):

Open `regedit` and go to  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General` key

The name of the key you are looking for is `WallpaperSource`

[image]

Comment: What software is that interface?

Comment: This is regedit / Registry Editor of Windows :)

Comment: With some extension, no? Mine does not have toolbars nor tabs nor a Window menu: https://i.imgur.com/n2FMD02.png

Comment: @sergiol If you are using Windows 10, you can enable that by going into View and selecting Address Bar

Comment: @pun I am using Windows 10 and I have not an "Address bar" option on the "View" menu. Not even running `regedit` as Administrator.

Comment: @sergiol [Which Windows 10 build are you using ?](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/66329-turn-off-address-bar-registry-editor-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 14):

While the answers from **duDE** & **CharlieRB** is correct

I also think what **OP** is looking for is in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\`

There would be a file called `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg` which is the currently set wallpaper

Comment: Yup. found it! Windows Photo Viewer was unable to open it but surprisingly, VLC was...

Comment: I can totally understand that cos one of my Windows shows **transcodedwallpaper** as unknown file. If i open it in paint or browse through any other software like photoshop it opens. Still i think it serves the purpose

Comment: I've a solid color set as my wallpaper, it doesn't point to that default system wallpaper, except in `CachedFiles`.

Comment: Often the file `TranscodedWallpaper` will have no file extension. If you rename the file to have one (such as `.jpg`) then it should open just fine by double clicking on it.

Comment: I found mine under the directory `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\RoamedThemeFiles\DesktopBackground`. Original name + file extension.

Answer (score 4):

Some wallpapers are also stored in this location:   `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets`

The images don't have an extension but paint will open them.  The larger files are the wallpapers.  Copy the ones you want to another folder and add `.jpg`.  List by date so you know when you get new ones.

Comment: Hello @drdave, Welcome to Super User! Nice answer! Note that these are the wallpapers downloaded and chosen by Windows 10 automatically, not the ones set by the user.

Comment: This is the Windows Spotlight storage location. Wallpapers are not stored at this location. Seriously, read the question.

Comment: LOL. You said that to the *author* of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to verify this because I am on a Windows 7 machine at the time...

You should be able to find the desktop and lock screen images in the `C:\Windows\Web\` in there you will find a `Wallpaper` and `Screen` folders.

The `Wallpaper` folder contains the desktop backgrounds while the `Screen` folder contains lock screen images.

[Source](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/windows-wallpaper-location/)

Comment: These folders only contained the default windows wallpapers, not ones which have been set by the user... :(

Answer (score -1):

I found it in cached files

\%appdata%\roaming\microsoft\windows\themes\cachedfiles

Comment: Your answer is very similar to @pun answer.